# No compatible network card

Tags: networking, adapter, esxi

Motherboard: Asus K8N-E Deluxe with onboard NIC (nVidia nForce)
Secondary NIC: I've tried using a standard NIC (Device Manager displays this as D-Link DFE-538TX 10/100, but under manufacturer in the General tab of the properties in Windows it states Realtek Semiconductor Corp.)

I have downloaded ESXi 4.0.0 build 208167 and cooked to disc. I've booted from it, the .TGZ modules load from the yellow and grey screen, the progress bar reaches to about 60% and like a second later the screen changes and I have the following information on screen;

"No compatible network adapter found. Please consult the HCG."

I've checked the HCG and found that my motherboard is listed. I also get the same message with the secondary NIC.

Any ideas please?

Comment: This question would be better suited on superuser.com

Comment: lets migrate it there, probably?

Comment: It will be migrated there once enough users have voted to migrate

Answer (score 1):

Buy an [Intel Gigabit CT (EXPI9301CT) PCIe x1 Card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CXWWBE), $35 and ESXi supported. Works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need the forcedeth drivers for you onboard networking and your other card is not on the list...

http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/io_reports.php?deviceCategory=io

Answer (score 0):

I really can't find any reference to ESXi 4U1 supporting your motherboard, it's built in nForce 3 250GB based NIC or your secondary D-Link/Realtek.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else said, nVidia nforce needs forcedeth drivers.

Try yet another network card.

I would recommend the 3COM 3C905 10/100 (you said your secondary was a 10/100)...they're supported by just about everything, perform well, and are quite common...BUT they're not on the list EK posted. (Surprising; the 3c905 even has DOS drivers.)

Try a generic Intel card. They're usually not too hard to get hold of, and there's a million of 'em on the list.